# How to hide a div element if there is no content

Tags: php, html

I have been able to successfully create a php statement that shows an icon and text label only if a custom field is completed by a user in wordpress.

The fields are in a div which adds  a background color.

I do not know how to wrap the div inside the php statement so that if the user does not complete the custom field the background  is not displayed in the front end of the website. Currently every post has a background

Please can someone show me how to apply this to my current code below

Your help is greatly appreciated:

```
<div id="tcntimes">
<?php
if(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)): ?>
<p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
<?php echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true); ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
  </div>
```

Kind regards

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)): ?>
    <div id="tcntimes">
    <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

For two fields, simply use the && operator in the IF which translates to AND, this way you verify on both values first and then display the div accordingly.

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true) && get_post_meta($id, "end_time", true)): ?>
    <div id="tcntimes">
    <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true); ?></p>
    <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "end_time", true); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Hi Salketer,

This worked exactly as I needed it to and the code was easy to follow allowing me to make future customisations.

Thank you for your time and assistance. I really appreciate it :)

Ricky

Comment: Hi Salketer, 

I would like to take this one final step further. If I wanted to show a single background container only if two meta fields have been completed can you advise how the div structure would change - my example is noted below:

<?php if(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)): ?>
    <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true); ?></p>

<?php endif;?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($id, "end_time", true)): ?>

    <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "end_time", true); ?></p>
<?php endif;?>

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how you could do using the exact same mechanic requiring that 2 fields are entered

Comment: I am very greatful Salketer - Thank you for all your help and responding so quickly. 

I tried your revision and it works perfectly allowing me to style the div and p elements. 

I know very little about php but I feel you have made somethings much easier to understand. 

Thank you

Ricky

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

```
<div id="tcntimes" style="<?php (get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)) ? echo 'display:block' : echo 'display:none'; ?>">
    <?php
    if(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)): ?>
    <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true); ?></p>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Re-reading OP I think that this is more suited... As he could simply take the background off by changing/addind a class. And always remember that using classes is better than inline style.

Comment: Hi MakC,

Thank you for your reply. I ended up using Salketeres recommendation, unfortunatly the code you submitted causes an error: :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in

Answer (score 0):

To hide container if it has no content you can you `:empty` pseudo selector:

```
div:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

Please also note, if container has even one space it is not counted as empty

[link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/)

Answer (score -1):

try this one also. It may help you

```
    <?php
    if(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)): ?>
    <div id="tcntimes" style="<?php (get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)) ? echo 'display:block' : echo 'display:none'; ?>">
        <p><img src="myimage.png"/> 
        <?php echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: a if inside a if with the exact same statement is NOT good practice... Plus it is completely useless

Comment: Hi Krish,

This doesnt work, the code returns and error. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in.....

I used Salketer's suggestion which worked for my needs. Thanks again for your time and assistance Krish.

Regards

Ricky

Comment: You get the error because `(get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true)) ? echo 'display:block' : echo 'display:none';` sould be `echo get_post_meta($id, "start_time", true) ? 'display:block' : 'display:none';`